# Degeneration of a metric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to understand how the metric degenerate on a family of projective varieties (mainly for abelian varieties.).

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{C}$. 
Let $B$ be a smooth projective curve and $\pi:X\to B$ be a surjective morphism. We give  $X$ a riemannian metric. Let $\mathbb{D}$ be a unit open disk in $B$ with origin $o$. Assume that $\pi$ is smooth over $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{o\}$  and the fiber above $o$ is simple normal crossing. I mainly interest in the case where general fibres of $\pi$ are abelian varieties.

Consider the morphism $T:=(0,1)\times \mathbf{R}\to \mathbb{D}\setminus\{o\}\subseteq B$ by $$(r, \theta)\mapsto re^{i\theta}.$$ 
We define a riemannian metric on $T$ by pull back the standard euclidean metric on $\mathbb{D}.$

The pull back $\tilde{X}:=X\times_BT$ is isomorphic to $X_b\times T$ where $b$ is a point in $\mathbb{D}$ and $X_b:=\pi^{-1}(b)$. On $\tilde{X}$ we have two riemannian metrics. The first one $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the pull back of the riemannian metrics on $X$. 
The other one $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the product metric on $X_b\times T$.

How can we compare these two metrics on $\tilde{X}$ when $r$ tends to $0$? For example, what is the order at $0$ of the function 
$$\rho(t):=\sup_{r(x)\geq t}(\|v_x\|_1/\|v_x\|_2)$$ where $v_x$ is a non-zero tangent vector at a point $x\in \tilde{X}$ with $r(x)\geq t.$

Comment: It seems that the identification $X\times_B T \cong X_b\times T$ is highly non-canonical.

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, I'm interested in the case where $X$ is a family of abelian varieties ( with some singular fibers), we have a canonical way to identify $X\times_BT$ with $X_b\times T$ by identifying the torsion sections.